# DDR2-800 (PC2-6400) RAM is clocked at 200MHz?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

It should be twice the frequency, right?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Intel 945GC specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/34505/Intel-82945GC-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [memory divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_divider) shows a ratio of 3:2 (`DRAM:FSB`). To get the effective clock speed of the memory, you multiply your memory divider by your CPU's bus speed.

According to your screen shots, your bus speed is `133 MHz`<sup>1</sup>, so taking that and doing a little math we get:

> `(3/2) * 133 = 199.5 MHz`

This is the memory clock speed, which for a [DDR2-800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM) module is 200 MHz and I/O bus clock is 400 MHz. Since it's DDR (double data rate), your data rate is 800 MT/s (mega-transfers a second), which is where the 800 in DDR2-800 comes from (not to be confused with [DDR3-1600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) which *does* have an 800 MHz bus clock).

<sup>1: your `rated FSB` is the `bus speed * 4` since the FSB is quad-pumped, hence the `533 MHz` metric though we use the `133 MHz` for calculations.</sup>

Hope that can help.

Comment: You failed to explained how to get to the 800 MHz.

Comment: @Ramhound, because DDR2 does not clock at 800MHz, OP was probably confused to the naming conventions .. thanks for pointing that out though, I've edited for clarity

Comment: Like the OP, I'm not sure how you get from 200 to 800 MHz. DDR implies double, so one would expect 400 -> 800, but where does the 400 come from?

Comment: @jcaron, there is no 800 MHz DDR2 .. there is DDR2-800, to which the 800 denotes it's transfer rate (not clock speed). DDR2-800 has a bus speed of 400 MHz and thus a data transfer rate of 800 MT/s (mega-transfers a second). The 200 MHz number is the memory clock speed (not the bus speed) which is what CPU-z is showing.

Comment: @txtechhelp so all DDR2-800 sticks use 200MHz? I have also added SPD table.

Comment: @txtechhelp, sorry, I did indeed mean 800 MT/s rather than MHz. But what I'm still missing is how we go from 200 to 400 (I understand the **d**DR explains the 400 -> 800).

Comment: @MarkEvans most of the number quoted are defacto standards .. that is, it can depend on the voltages supplied, bus speed, clock, and other motherboard/CPU factors, but generally speaking, yes that's the memory clock speed. What's more important though is how fast it can transfer the data (not so much the clock speed) because you could have a low bus speed but high data transfer (as with DDR3), which depends on the memory itself (more than say the CPU or motherboard).

Comment: @jcaron, actually, the DDR is for the 200->400 .. the 200 MHz is the clock, where double data rate means there's a 'pump' on the up and down cycle, so 200 MHz DDR is 400 MHz .. the 800 is the number derived from the standard .. so DDR2-1066 has a transfer rate of 1066 MT/s, but it's clock speed can vary .. the DDR2-XXXX is a naming convention to denote the transfer rate where as the PC2-XXXX is to denote theoretical bandwidth, so DDR2-800 has a transfer rate of 800 MT/s while it's PC2-6400 module has a theoretical throughput of ~6400MB/s .. confusing .. yes :)